# Correct framework for different attribute values in Dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, attributes, data-warehouse, dimensions

I am attempting to build a Customer dimension from about 5 of our underlying systems.I have a situation where each system has varying degrees of data quality and as a result I end up with different values for the same attributes across rows.

I need to merge the rows into a single row (as it is the same customer and need to be able to merge and make a golden record)

I am running MS SQL Server 2019.

So my data looks something like this (from source system):

```
ClientID, PhoneNumber, Address, SourceSystemID
123, 63310042, '123 Test Street, Test Town, 2800,', SAP
123,+61310042,'123 test st, Test town 2800', Netsuite
```

I am wondering what the best apporach here is because I want to:

1. ensure that transaction from source system SAP, and Netsuite are shown whenever I view this customer.
2. I also want the analyse geographical information like. - they are from 'Test Town'

Comment: You didn't actually tell us what you expect your final result to be here. If we don't know your end goal, it's very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry i thought i did - i want to know how people handle this in the DW? Reject the data? feed it back to the business for editing? Pick on of the rows and use that?

Comment: Asking "what is best" is off topic for SO; they generate opinionated ansers. If you're asking a "how to", and can show the results your after and your attempts we can help you with that but this doesn't appear to be a programming quesion.

Comment: Its not really off topic, its trying to determine the best solution to a problem.

Comment: That is my point; asking "what is best" *is* generally off topic. It produces opinionated answered based on experience rather than facts.